# how to fix epoch time to datetime in Python Date Time and micro sec resolution

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

epoch time coversion diffrent results(pandas and datetime), which one to use?
i have epoch time in two variables

```
utc=1558488564  # Epoch count
us =539473   #micro second data

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1558488564.539473)
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 22, 6, 59, 24, 539473)

pd.to_datetime(1558488564.539473, unit='s')
Timestamp('2019-05-22 01:29:24.539473057')


pd.to_datetime(1558488564539473, unit='us')
Timestamp('2019-05-22 01:29:24.539473')

22.05.19 05:29:24,539473
```

Final Solution below, both gives same result

```
time_offset= 330
pd.to_datetime(utc+'.'+us, unit='s')+timedelta(minutes=int(time_offset)) 
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(utc+'.'+us))+timedelta(minutes=int(time_offset))
```

Answer (score -1):

The difference is local versus UTC time, it depends which one you want to use:

[image]